# Factory Girl trouble in initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot

I have a model where multiple params are passed to the initialize during object instantiation. Is there a way how i can skip the method from getting executed at all in factorygirl.

My model file is shown below:

```
class WebResponseCache < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :q, :results

  self.table_name = "web_response_cache"

  def initialize(q, results)
    super()
    self.q = q
    self.results = results
  end
```

My factory girl code is shown below:

```
FactoryGirl.define do    
  factory :google_web_response_cache, :class => WebResponseCache do
    initialize_with { new('query', 'results') }
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have any error when using this factory? Why would you want to skip the method?

Answer (score 3):

You can't skip this method from getting executed, as it is the constructor. But you can change it in order to make the parameters unnecessary.

```
  def initialize(attrs = nil)
    super()
    return unless attrs

    self.q = attrs[:q]
    self.results = attrs[:results]
  end
```

Now you can do

```
WebResponseCache.new # no params passed
WebResponseCache.new(q: 'query', results: 'results') # will be initialized with given params
```

And now you don't need `initialize_with` block in your factory.